# how to do this query with 2 different aggregates

Tags: postgresql

I got 2 tables (conversations and messages):

```
CREATE TABLE public.convs (
    conv_id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    user_id1 int4 NOT NULL,
    user_id2 int4 NOT NULL,
    created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT conv_pkey PRIMARY KEY (conv_id)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE public.conv_messages (
    conv_message_id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    conv_id int4 NOT NULL,
    message text NOT NULL,
    message_type int2 NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    unread bool NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    from_user_id int4 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT convmessages_pkey PRIMARY KEY (conv_message_id)
);
```

and want a list of recent conversations with unread counts:

```
select distinct on (c.conv_id) c.conv_id 
   , m.message
   , m.message_type
   , count(m.unread or null) over(partition by c.conv_id) as unreads
   , m.from_user_id
   , u.user_name
FROM convs c
   left JOIN conv_messages m using (conv_id)
   join users u on m.from_user_id = u.user_id
where 6000 IN (user_id1, user_id2)  
group by c.conv_id, m.conv_message_id, u.user_id
having m.from_user_id <> 6000
order by c.conv_id desc, m.conv_message_id desc
limit 10;
```

and here is the result of some test data:

```
conv_id|last_message|message_type|unreads|from_user_id|user_name|
-------|------------|------------|-------|------------|---------|
  20738|reply msg 3 |           1|      2|        6005|Hillegom |
  20737|last msg    |           1|      2|        6004|Oudewater|
  20736|reply msg 3 |           1|      2|        6003|Rockanje |
  20735|reply msg 3 |           1|      2|        6002|Heerlen  |
  20734|reply msg 3 |           1|      2|        6001|Bergen   |
```

The only problem I have here is that the `HAVING` clause is being used to get the unread counts for only user 6000, but I *also* want the last_message. Because of the having clause I can't get to the last message, but if I remove the clause I can't get the correct counts. How do I solve this in an efficient way? I tried to use a sub-query for the counts but the performance impact is quite high.

**EDIT - data that got to these results:**

conversations:

```
conv_id|user_id1|user_id2|created                   |
-------|--------|--------|--------------------------|
  20734|    6000|    6001|2019-04-21 16:10:43.931866|
  20735|    6000|    6002|2019-04-21 16:10:58.068944|
  20736|    6000|    6003|2019-04-21 16:11:07.986172|
  20737|    6000|    6004|2019-04-21 16:11:21.571927|
  20738|    6000|    6005|   2019-04-21 16:11:32.344|
```

messages:

```
conv_message_id|conv_id|message    |message_type|created                   |unread|from_user_id|
---------------|-------|-----------|------------|--------------------------|------|------------|
          72836|  20734|last msg   |           1|2019-04-21 16:10:43.931866|true  |        6000|
          72835|  20734|reply msg 3|           1|2019-04-21 16:10:43.931866|true  |        6001|
          72834|  20734|reply msg 2|           1|2019-04-21 16:10:43.931866|true  |        6001|
          72833|  20734|msg 1      |           1|2019-04-21 16:10:43.931866|true  |        6000|
          72840|  20735|last msg   |           1|2019-04-21 16:10:58.068944|true  |        6000|
          72839|  20735|reply msg 3|           1|2019-04-21 16:10:58.068944|true  |        6002|
          72838|  20735|reply msg 2|           1|2019-04-21 16:10:58.068944|true  |        6002|
          72837|  20735|msg 1      |           1|2019-04-21 16:10:58.068944|true  |        6000|
          72844|  20736|last msg   |           1|2019-04-21 16:11:07.986172|true  |        6000|
          72843|  20736|reply msg 3|           1|2019-04-21 16:11:07.986172|true  |        6003|
          72842|  20736|reply msg 2|           1|2019-04-21 16:11:07.986172|true  |        6003|
          72841|  20736|msg 1      |           1|2019-04-21 16:11:07.986172|true  |        6000|
          72848|  20737|last msg   |           1|2019-04-21 16:11:21.571927|true  |        6004|
          72847|  20737|reply msg 3|           1|2019-04-21 16:11:21.571927|true  |        6000|
          72846|  20737|reply msg 2|           1|2019-04-21 16:11:21.571927|true  |        6000|
          72845|  20737|msg 1      |           1|2019-04-21 16:11:21.571927|true  |        6004|
          72852|  20738|last msg   |           1|   2019-04-21 16:11:32.344|true  |        6000|
          72851|  20738|reply msg 3|           1|   2019-04-21 16:11:32.344|true  |        6005|
          72850|  20738|reply msg 2|           1|   2019-04-21 16:11:32.344|true  |        6000|
          72849|  20738|msg 1      |           1|   2019-04-21 16:11:32.344|true  |        6005|
```

What I want is simple really, the conversation id, last_message and unread messages. In the data above the text 'last msg' is really the last inserted record for this conversation.

Comment: Your combined used of `DISTINCT ON`, `GROUP BY`, and the use of analytic functions, all at the same time, seems confusing to me.  You might want to include some sample data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added the sample data.